# Create a event Booking calendar with Jquery datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

Is it possible to create a event booking calendar with Jquery datepciker ?
See the calendar picture below

[image]

For example when I booked a full day for a event in a place, date will be red , for only day it will be yellow and for only night it will be green in the date cell.When I click a date it grab the date and bring the booking form and booked for fullday/day/night etc.Give me some idea.

Comment: With a plugin like [Fullcalndar](https://fullcalendar.io/) you can do that and more...

Comment: Can I make Fullcalender smaller like the example  and customize it like above calendar ?

Comment: you can really do whatever you want with it. Different styles, different methods and listeners that detect clicks and change values of everything on the cal. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/waspinator/H399a/) is one example of mini mode.

Comment: Looks nice  Thank You !   Can  I integrate php and ajax with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to show some colors on some particular dates of the jQuery datepicker...

You can use the `beforeShowDay` and a function to check if the date is in a given array...
Then, based on which array it is found in, add a class to the date.
And you can decide to disable the date (can't be selected).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var red = ["2017-08-02","2017-08-04","2017-08-06"];
  var yellow = ["2017-08-09"];
  var green = ["2017-08-10","2017-08-11"];

  $("#calendar").datepicker({
    defaultDate: '08/07/2017',      // Just for this demo longevity on SO ;)
    
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      var dateISO = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      //console.log(dateISO);

      if(red.indexOf(dateISO)>-1){
        return [true,"red"]        // Enabled, class
      }
      if(yellow.indexOf(dateISO)>-1){
        return [true,"yellow"]
      }
      if(green.indexOf(dateISO)>-1){
        return [true,"green"]
      }
      return [true]  // If not found, must at least return the enabled boolean.
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.red a{
  background-color: red !important;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.yellow a{
  background-color: yellow !important;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.green a{
  background-color: green !important;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```